# Unexpected behaviour when scanf used inside while loop to read an array

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, scanf

I wrote a program to read digits into array of integers a[100]. And the reading stops when the user enters a character 'e' or when array reached the maximum size.

But when the code is run, I got an unexpected behavior that, when user enters 'e' the scanning of digits into array terminates as I intended in program, but rest of the statements inside while loop including increment variable (i++) and printf functions I used to debug the the code until the first condition inside while's condition part become false.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int a[100];
puts("Enter numbers(enter \"e\" to stop entring)\n");
int i=0;
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
while(i<100&&a[i]!='e'){
     i++;;
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     printf("\n -----> %d\n",i);
}
printf("\n\t i ---> %d\t\n",i);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `a[i]!='e'`??? I thought you wanted to scan integers. Yes, the `'e'` is extended to `int`, but if that's really what you're trying to achieve, then why aren't you using a `char` array, and why aren't you scanning `'%c'`?

Comment: Check return value of `scanf` and answer should be obvious.

Comment: `while(i<100 && a[i] !='e'` is comparing with an uninitialized array.

Answer (score 1):

Issues that I can think of:

1. The incrementing of the array index needs to be updated.

   ```
   while(i<100&&a[i]!='e'){
        // When i 99 before this statement, i becomes 100 after the increment
        i++;;
        // Now you are accessing a[100], which is out of bounds.
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
       printf("\n -----> %d\n",i);
   }
   ```

   what you need is:

   ```
   while(i<100&&a[i]!='e'){
       scanf("%d",&a[i]);
       printf("\n -----> %d\n",i);
       i++;;
   }
   ```
2. If your input stream contains an `e`, the statement

   ```
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   ```

   won't read anything to `a[i]`.

   You can fix that by:

   1. Read the input as a string.
   2. Check whether the string is `e`. If so, break out of the loop.
   3. If not, try to get the number from the string.

   Here's an updated version:

   ```
   char token[100]; // Make it large enough 
   while(i<100) {
       scanf("%s", token);
       if ( token[0] == 'e' ) // Add code to skip white spaces if you 
                              // want to if that's a possibility.
       {
          break;
       }
       sscanf(token, "%d", &a[i]);
       printf("\n -----> %d\n",i);
       i++;;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using `scanf()` family of functions, be sure to check the return value. (@user694733)

Using `scanf("%d",&a[i]);` to read "e" fails and `scanf()` returns 0 indicating no conversion occurred.  "e" remains in `stdin` until it can be properly read, which is never with OP's code, blocking subsequent input.

Read user input as a string, test if "e", else convert to `int`

```
int main(void) {
  int a[100];
  puts("Enter numbers(enter \"e\" to stop entering)\n");
  int i = 0;
  for (;;) {
    char buf[50];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      break;  // Input was closed
    }
    if (strcmp(buf, "e\n") == 0) {
      break; // normal method to stop entering.
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &a[i]) != 1) {  // or use strtod()
      break; // Some other garbage entered.
    }
    printf("\n -----> %d %d\n", i, a[i]);
    i++;  // increment afterwards @R Sahu
  }
  printf("\n\t i ---> %d\t\n",i);
  return 0; 
}
```

Note: suggest never use `scanf()`